# How do I show a list of hyperlinks used in the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my class I'm making 3 drop down menus for desserts and the recipes to make them. All the recipes are hyperlinks. I need to use JavaScript to show a list of all the actual links I used in the page.

Here is a link to what the page SHOULD look like (I'm trying to make the bottom part that says "Websites referenced in this document")

http://postimg.org/image/k3r58jw1b/

This is the code I've done so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Easy Dessert Recipes</title>

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> 

  <script src="scripts/jquery.zoom.min.js"></script> 

  <style type="text/css">

  h2 {
 background: url(images/open.png) no-repeat 0 11px;
 padding: 10px 0 0 25px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
 
h2.close {
 background-image: url(images/close.png);
 }
 
.menu {
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color:  rgba(0,0,0,.05);
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 
.recipes {
 margin-left: 25px; 
 }

</style>

<script>  

 $(document).ready(function() {  // this function makes the menu become a drop down menu
   
  $('.recipes').hide();
  $('.main h2').click(function() {
 var $recipes = $(this).next('.recipes');
 if ($recipes.is(':hidden')) {
  $recipes.slideDown();
  $(this).addClass('close');
 } else {
  $recipes.fadeOut();
  $(this).removeClass('close');
 }

   }); // end click

//-------------------------------------Zoom Function--------------------------------------   
   
 $("#ex1").zoom();  // these lines make the image zoom when you mouse over because of the zoom jquery file
 $("#ex2").zoom();
 $("#ex3").zoom();

//-----------------------------------MouseOver Function---------------------------------- 

 $('img').mouseover(function() {
 $("#popup").width(200).height(200);
 }); // End mouseover
 
 $("img").mouseout(function() {
 //$("#popup").width(200).height(200);
 $('#popup').remove();
 }); // End mouseout
 
//------------------------------------------Reference-----------------------------------


// Get all links to point outside of the site
  
//---------------------------------------END READY--------------------------------------   
   
   }); // end ready
 
   
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
   
   <header>Chapter 5 Lab</header>
   
 <div class="content">
   <div class="main">
   
<!--------------------------------------BEGIN Mini Cookies--------------------------> 
   
   <div class="menu">
   
   <h2>Mini Cookies</h2>
 
  <div class="recipes">  
   
      <p>
    Soft Mini Chocolate Chip Cookies – No one can resist a soft and chewy cookie, especially when it’s in mini form!         
      <a href="http://diethood.com/soft-mini-chocolate-chip-cookies/#QecOGKvhKY1KvAYG.99">Find Recipe Here</a>
   
      </p>
   
   <span class='zoom' id='ex1'>
     <img src='images/miniCookies.PNG' width='100' height='100' alt='bar'/>
   </span>
   
  </div>
   </div>
<!--------------------------------------END Mini Cookies-------------------------->   

<!--------------------------------------BEGIN Cookie Pie-------------------------->

   <div class="menu">
 
    <h2>Cookie Pie</h2>
 
     <div class="recipes">  
   
      <p>
    There's only one thing better then cookies and that GIGANTIC cookie.  Especially one's the size of pies!
   
      <a href="http://pinchofyum.com/deep-dish-chocolate-chip-cookie-with-caramel-sea-salt">Find Recipe Here</a>
   
      </p>
   
   <span class='zoom' id='ex2'>
     <img src='images/cookie.PNG' width='100' height='100' alt='bar'/>
   </span>
   
   </div>
   </div>
   
<!------------------------------------END Cookie Pie--------------------------------------->

<!-------------------------------- BEGIN Peanut Butter & Jelly Bars -----------------------> 
   
   <div class="menu">
   
  <h2>Peanut Butter & Jelly Bars</h2>
 
     <div class="recipes">  
   
      <p>
    You guys. I don’t even know what to say, other than if you make these bars you’ll want to eat every last crumb!
   
      <a href="http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/peanut-butter-and-jelly-bars-recipe.html">Find Recipe Here</a>
   
      </p>
   
   <span class='zoom' id='ex3'>
     <img src='images/bar.png' width='100' height='100' alt='bar'/>
   </span>
   
  
    </div>
    
    </div>

<!-------------------------- END Peanut Butter & Jelly Bars ------------------------------->    
   
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
 
 <footer>
  <p>Made by</p>
 </footer>
 
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure where to place the JavaScript and if I'm suppose to make another div and then link the JavaScript to it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? To get you started.......`$('a').each(function(i, link){ // .. do stuff with each link});`

Comment: What have you tried? Generally SO tries to avoid straight up doing homework assignments for people. @DelightedD0D gave you a good start.

Comment: I was attempting to do something like this to get it to work:

2 <script>

3 $(document).ready(function() {

4 $('span.pq').each(function() {

5 var quote=$(this).clone();

6 quote.removeClass('pq');

7 quote.addClass('pullquote');

8 $(this).before(quote);

9 }); // end each

10 }); // end ready

11 </script>

sorry I'm not sure how to post code correctly in a reply

Comment: I also tried adding $('selector').each(); to the code but I'm not sure if that's right and/or if I'm placing it in the right spot and also if I'm suppose to make another div for it to display the links.

Comment: The code you posted in your comment above does not appear to have anything at all to do with your question.....

Comment: I got it to work!

this is the javascript I added:
`$('a[href^="http://"]').each(function() {
var extLink = $(this).attr('href');
$('#RecipeList').append('<li>' + extLink + '</li>');
});`

And this is the HTML I added to the end of the page:

`<div id="refrences">
    
    <h3>Links for recipes</h3>
    <ul id="RecipeList">
    </ul>
    </ul>
    
    </div>`

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thanks for the help.  What you guys said helped me figure out what to look for in my book and between all that I got it working.  You can see in my previous comment the code I used to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution to my question:

At the end of the JavaScript code but right before the end ready }); I added:

```
    $('a[href^="http://"]').each(function() {
    var extLink = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#RecipeList').append('<li>' + extLink + '</li>');
    });
```

At the bottom of my HTML I made a new div with this code:

```
    <div id="references">  
    <h3>Links for recipes</h3>
    <ul id="RecipeList">
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Then to give it a better looking background I made this in the CSS:

```
    #references {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color:  rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

So altogether the whole code looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>

      <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <title>Easy Dessert Recipes</title>

      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> 

        <script src="scripts/jquery.zoom.min.js"></script> 

        <style type="text/css">

        h2 {
        background: url(images/open.png) no-repeat 0 11px;
        padding: 10px 0 0 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        }

      h2.close {
        background-image: url(images/close.png);
        }

      .menu  {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color:  rgba(0,0,0,.05);
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

      .recipes {
        margin-left: 25px;  
        }

      #references   {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color:  rgba(0,0,0,.05);
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
          }
      </style>

      <script>  

       $(document).ready(function() {  // this function makes the menu become a drop down menu

        $('.recipes').hide();
        $('.main h2').click(function() {
        var $recipes = $(this).next('.recipes');
        if ($recipes.is(':hidden')) {
            $recipes.slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('close');
        } else {
            $recipes.fadeOut();
            $(this).removeClass('close');
        }

         }); // end click

      //-------------------------------------Zoom Function--------------------------------------   

        $("#ex1").zoom();  // these lines make the image zoom when you mouse           over because of the zoom jquery file
        $("#ex2").zoom();
        $("#ex3").zoom();

       //-----------------------------------MouseOver Function----------------------------------              

      $('img').mouseover(function() {
        $("#popup").width(200).height(200);
        }); // End mouseover

      $("img").mouseout(function() {
        //$("#popup").width(200).height(200);
        $('#popup').remove();
        }); // End mouseout

      //------------------------------------------Reference-----------------------------------


      // Get all links to point outside of the site
      $('a[href^="http://"]').each(function() {
      var extLink = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#RecipeList').append('<li>' + extLink + '</li>');
      });
      //---------------------------------------END READY--------------------------------------   

         }); // end ready


      </script>

      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="wrapper">

          <header>Chapter 5 Lab</header>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="main">

      <!--------------------------------------BEGIN Mini Cookies--------------------------> 

          <div class="menu">

          <h2>Mini Cookies</h2>

            <div class="recipes">  

                   <p>
                    Soft Mini Chocolate Chip Cookies – No one can resist a soft and chewy cookie, especially when it’s in mini form!                  
                      <a href="http://diethood.com/soft-mini-chocolate-chip-cookies/#QecOGKvhKY1KvAYG.99">Find Recipe Here</a>

                   </p>

                <span class='zoom' id='ex1'>
                  <img src='images/miniCookies.PNG' width='100' height='100' alt='bar'/>
                </span>

            </div>
          </div>
      <!--------------------------------------END Mini Cookies-------------------------->     

      <!--------------------------------------BEGIN Cookie Pie-------------------------->

          <div class="menu">

           <h2>Cookie Pie</h2>

               <div class="recipes">  

                   <p>
                    There's only one thing better then cookies and that GIGANTIC cookie.  Especially one's the size of pies!

                      <a href="http://pinchofyum.com/deep-dish-chocolate-chip-cookie-with-caramel-sea-salt">Find Recipe Here</a>

                   </p>

                <span class='zoom' id='ex2'>
                  <img src='images/cookie.PNG' width='100' height='100' alt='bar'/>
                </span>

             </div>
          </div>

      <!------------------------------------END Cookie Pie--------------------------------------->

      <!-------------------------------- BEGIN Peanut Butter & Jelly Bars ----------------------->  

          <div class="menu">

             <h2>Peanut Butter & Jelly Bars</h2>

               <div class="recipes">  

                   <p>
                    You guys. I don’t even know what to say, other than if you make these bars you’ll want to eat every last crumb!

                      <a href="http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/peanut-butter-and-jelly-bars-recipe.html">Find Recipe Here</a>

                   </p>

                <span class='zoom' id='ex3'>
                  <img src='images/bar.png' width='100' height='100' alt='bar'/>
                </span>


              </div>

           </div>

      <!-------------------------- END Peanut Butter & Jelly Bars ------------------------------->     

              <div id="references">

              <h3>Links for recipes</h3>
              <ul id="RecipeList">
              </ul>

              </div>


          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>Made by </p>
        </footer>

        </div>

      </body>
      </html>
```